Could opening an .xla file with Trojan virus infect a Windows PC even through the Excel Read-Only view?
I made the mistake of opening an email attachment in Thunderbird. It was a .xla file, which I opened directly in Excel. The moment that the Excel window popped-up I closed it, realising the mistake I've done.
I ran antivirus checks with Malwarebytes and BitDefender which confirmed the file's malicious. Virustotal.com also flagged the file as malicious. A trojan horse, Agent Tesla type. So I deleted the files and ran more checks, but nothing came up.
I read a bit about .xla files and macros, as I didn't really know how they worked before. Usually all Excel files are opened in "Read-only" or Protected mode, which I believe limits the possibility of running a virus.
Do you think the file infected my PC and I should wipe it clean and reinstall Windows?

If Malwarebytes says your machine is clean now, then that Agent Tesla tojan is gone.

Did you get the yellow bar at the top of the worksheet, under the Ribbon bar?

@spikey_richie, I closed the window before anything has been visualized.

Excel by default requires action to run macros, so unless you changed the default (File>Options>Trust Center>Macro Settings) to enable macros you should have one less avenue worry about.
